# /usr/bin/python3: No module named pip

Tags: python

Why does this happen?

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

Surely this should be easy to fix.

Comment: because you have not installed `pip` maybe?

Answer (score 4):

`pip` is not installed by default.

Install via `apt`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Or alternative methods described in the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation).

Comment: You might need to run `sudo apt-get update` before this.

Comment: true, added, thanks! :-)